# JQuery remove the full link when click at the end of the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on jquery to remove the link. I need some help with my code because I am having a hard time to remove the link when I click at the end of the text and click on a button to remove the full link in the same line.

When I try this:

```
else if (window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0))
{
    document.execCommand('unlink', false, selected_text);
}
```

It will not remove the link unless I have to highlight on the text and click on a button to remove the link.

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#toolbar_unlink', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var selected_text = window.getSelection() ? "" + window.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().text;


    if (selected_text) {
        document.execCommand('unlink', false, selected_text);
    }
    else if (window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0))
    {
        selected = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer.wholeText;
        console.log(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0));

        document.execCommand('unlink', false, selected_text);
        //clearSelection();
    }
});
```

When I highlight on the text and click on the button, it will remove the link with no problem. So I when I click at the end of the text and click on the button, it will not remove the full link.

However, when I click at the end of the text I will get the full text `Video Here 2` without the link.

Here is the html:

```
<div id="toolbar" class="toolbar_top" role="toolbar" style="height: 100px; user-select: none;">
    <button id="toolbar_unlink" class="toolbar_button toolbar_button_unlink_icon" command="+unlink" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Remove link (‪CTRL+SHIFT+F9)" style="user-select: none; position: relative; margin-left: 3px; margin-top: 13px; outline: none; z-index: 0;" button="" type="button"></button>
</div>

<div id="text_editor" class="editor_message" hidefocus="false" aria-label="Message Body" g_editable="true" role="textbox" aria-hidden="true" aria-multiline="true" contenteditable="true" tabindex="1" style="direction: ltr; height: 500px; width: 100%; padding-left: 25px; padding-top: 18px; font-size: 16px; border-bottom: 1px solid #d1d1d1; border-right: 1px solid #d1d1d1; border-left: 1px solid #d1d1d1; overflow-y: auto;" itacorner="6,7:1,1,0,0">
    <div><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHyIq3boCu0" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DdHyIq3boCu0&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1577810994184000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFaXvqSKIPAwOUGOicDn-cMTWvW_w">Video Here 1!</a></div>
    <div><a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.google.com/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1577810994184000&amp;usg=AFQjCNEaLRLcUmjjRiAPYptws9xd7P5A5w">Video Here 2!</a></div><div></div>
</div>
```

I cant find a way for a solution how to remove the link using document.execCommand function even I have tried everything and I have got no luck.

Here is what I have already tried:

```
document.execCommand('unlink', false, selected_text);
```

And when I tried this:
    $('#link').contents().unwrap();

It will remove all of the links when I only want to remove one link when I click on the text or at the end of the link.

Can you please show me an example how I can remove the link when I click at the end of the text and click on a button to remove the link?

Thank you.

Comment: Also include what you have tried.

Comment: @justDan I have tried `document.execCommand('unlink', false, selected_text);` so far no luck

Comment: @justDan And I have also tried `$('#link').contents().unwrap();` which it will remove all of the links. I only want to remove one link when I click on the text where the link are.

Comment: Can you send us full html (with) button?

Comment: Well, the moment you click the button to remove the link, you de-select any text that was previously selected, so that makes perfect sense why it doesn't work. I think you have more of a UX issue than a coding one.

Comment: @ttrasn Please check in my updated question.

Comment: Any idea??????????????????????????????